# Spring Boot Gradle Script - Get mainClassName

Tags: gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

If I have:

build.gradle

```
 System.out.println("${tasks.bootJar.mainClassName}")
```

> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

So I comment out System.out.println, run the build again.  Success.

Now if I uncomment out my System.out.println the main class name properly prints until I do a gradle clean.

Clearly some predicate job is running and being cached and that result is necessary for the println to work.   Can anyone tell me how I can figure out which task it is and how to force it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't understand how to properly troubleshoot this (ie a good reference on debugging task ordering and such).    In my particular instance, browsing around on Github I found a more specific property which seems to always be available for mainClassName

tasks.bootJar.properties.mainClassName